# Longtable with landscape

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

I need to make a table that spans several pages, likely in landscape format. The code that I have pasted below works well, but I need it to be `longtable` instead of `table` so that I can continue adding rows of information without going beyond the page dimensions. When I replace `table` with `longtable`, I get an error message:

> Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\caption): `c' used.

I should also add that I have the following in my preamble so that tables are APA formatted, and so that I can have automatically-numbered row.

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[1ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt, belowskip=-10pt}

 \preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}.}
```

Below is my table. Any thoughts here? Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Table Caption Goes Here}
\label{table_lable}
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm} p{10.75cm} p{3.25cm} p{3.75cm}}
\toprule
No. & Header1 & Header2 & Header3 \\
\midrule 
{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & (a) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text text text  & text text text text text text  \\

& (b) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & text text text text text text  & text text text text text text  \\

& (c) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & text text text text & text text text text  \\

{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & (a) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\

& (b) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\

{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\bigskip
%\small\textit{Note}. 
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Regarding "When I replace table with longtable":  Replace `tabular` with `longtable`, remove the `table` environment and place `\caption  and `\label` inside of the `longtable` environment. Don't forget to add a `\\ ` after the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[1ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt, belowskip=-10pt}

 \preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}.}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{p{1cm} p{10.75cm} p{3.25cm} p{3.75cm}}
\caption{Table Caption Goes Here}
\label{table_lable}\\
\toprule
No. & Header1 & Header2 & Header3 \\
\midrule 
\endfirsthead
\caption{Table Caption Goes Here - continued from previous page}
\label{table_lable}\\
\toprule
No. & Header1 & Header2 & Header3 \\
\midrule 
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & (a) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text text text  & text text text text text text  \\

& (b) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & text text text text text text  & text text text text text text  \\

& (c) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text & text text text text & text text text text  \\

{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & (a) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\

& (b) text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\

{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\

{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\

{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\

{\makebox[0.5cm][l]{1-\rownumber}} & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  & text text text text & text text text text  \\
\end{longtable}


\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :)